# TypeScript async boolean function won't fetch promise function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to fetch a different height and width parameter depending on whether I'm dealing with a video or image.

But I keep getting a `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error when I fetch the `checkDimension` function.

I've double checked the code and do not see any program syntax errors.

Could it be that I'm calling the async function wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
const checkDimension = async (
  word:string,
): Promise<boolean> => {
  let check=true;
  let dimension= await dimensions(word);
  if (dimension.width < 10 || dimension.height <10) {
      check=false;
    return Promise.resolve(check);
  } else if (dimension.width > 10 || dimension.height >10){
      check=false;
    return Promise.resolve(check);
  } 
  return Promise.resolve(check);
};

console.log(checkDimension('image'));

const dimensions = (
    word:string
  ): Promise<{ width: number; height: number }> => {
    const promise = new Promise<{ width: number; height: number }>(
      (resolve, reject) => {
          if(word==='image'){
          const width = 100;
          const height = 100;
          resolve({ width, height });
          }
        reject;
      },
    );
  
    return promise;
  };
```

Comment: No error. See here: https://tsplay.dev/NBeypw

Comment: There error you're getting cannot come from calling a method in a certain way, its a syntax error. Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

In your code I receive:

```
ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: dimensions is not a function
TypeError: dimensions is not a function
```

dimensions is undefined at that moment
Try this:

```
const dimensions = (
      word: string
    ): Promise<{ width: number; height: number }> => {
      const promise = new Promise<{ width: number; height: number }>(
        (resolve, reject) => {
          if (word === 'image') {
            const width = 100;
            const height = 100;
            resolve({ width, height });
          }
          reject;
        }
      );

      return promise;
    };
    const checkDimension = async (word: string): Promise<boolean> => {
      let check = true;
      let dimension = await dimensions(word);
      if (dimension.width < 10 || dimension.height < 10) {
        check = false;
        return Promise.resolve(check);
      } else if (dimension.width > 10 || dimension.height > 10) {
        check = false;
        return Promise.resolve(check);
      }
      return Promise.resolve(check);
    };

    console.log(checkDimension('image'));
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help at all. I've tried this.

Comment: @Vakindu could you please provide the whole working code and where error occurs(line of code with stack trace) or  provide the example to https://stackblitz.com/ just to make sure that I check/debug the correct situation.
By the way, you have `reject;` without calling it inside the dimensions  function.